# Dot pagination with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, pagination

i m very much new to programming with JavaScript and would love to gain more experience, my problem isn't actually a problem, it more like of optimizing a code, I've been working on making what so called a "pagination" a dot navigation. you can find my code example in this code pen https://codepen.io/Tarek-Chentouf/pen/ajqXpW .  My code goes as follow:

```
"use strict";

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button__outline');

function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
}

function addActive() {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (i == 0) {
                reset();
                buttons[0].classList.add('active');
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                reset();
                buttons[1].classList.add('active');
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                reset();
                buttons[2].classList.add('active');
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                reset();
                buttons[3].classList.add('active');
            }
        });
    }
}
addActive();
```

my Question goes as follow is there a better way to achieve the same result without having to repeat the if statement?. 
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, you could simply access `buttons[i]` instead of `if (i == 0) ... buttons[0] ... if (i == 1) ... buttons[1] ...`:

```
function addActive() {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      reset();
      buttons[i].classList.add('active');
    });
  }
}
```

But you could make the code cleaner and DRY-er with a `forEach` - instead of accessing an index of the `buttons` collection, abstract the button being iterated over into a variable of its own:

```
function addActive() {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      reset();
      button.classList.add('active');
    });
  });
}
```

Or, as Patrick Roberts suggested, you might move all the `classList` changes into the `reset` function and use event delegation on the container (that way you only need one listener, rather than many):

```
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.button__outline')) return;
  reset(target);
});
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button__outline');
function reset(showButton) {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.classList.remove('active');
  })
  showButton.classList.add('active');
}
reset(buttons[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked perfectly, and thank you for the lesson.

Comment: +1 for the second case. Would your first code block work, though, or is the click handler closing over `i`, causing `i` to be the post-loop value?

Comment: @Jacob `i` is declared with `let`, so each iteration has a separate binding for it - it'll work.

Comment: It would probably be better to `function setActive () { reset(); this.classList.add('active'); } function addActive () { buttons.forEach(button => { button.addEventListener('click', setActive); }); }` to re-use the same function rather than creating one for each button. Or use delegated event listening to handle all the buttons with one event listener set in a parent element.